# Problem with button with IE driver and Xpath Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, button, xpath, click

i have the follow problem:

I have a button inside a form (the web page have a login and password text box and a button), this button calls a js funtion and after the login and password validation, calls the main web page. The html code is this (this code is inside of a form calls "login" and method = POST):

```
<INPUT class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" onclick=submitForm(); type=button value="Sign On">
```

In Selenium i try with the follow statements, but without success:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='button']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][@value='Sign On']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Sign On']")).click();
```

when i run the script, login and password text are filled correctly, but the click in the button it's no working.

Could you help me with this?

Thanks!

Gonzalo from Chile

Comment: Can you provide the url on which you are trying your script?

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][@value='Sign On']")).click();` for sure this doesn't work as you have `@value` rather `value` in the css. Please share the html of the the element and also make sure the element is not present in the iframe.

Comment: Is the login button hidden before entering username and password? If so, IE browser sometimes have trouble recognizing previously hidden elements. One option to fix this is to Waitforelement to be visible and use Actions class to click the element.

Comment: before the button, i got this:   <INPUT type=hidden name=postpreservationdata>
  <INPUT class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" onclick=submitForm(); type=button value="Sign On">. I have to say, this is private code, that's the reason why i can't put the entire code here.

Comment: this is the code of the form: <FORM method=post name=Login><INPUT type=hidden value=ISO-8859-1 name=SMENC> <INPUT type=hidden value=US-EN name=SMLOCALE> 
<LABEL id=userLabel>Username</LABEL> <INPUT class=txtBox style="MARGIN-LEFT: 1px" maxLength=7 size=30 name=USER> <LABEL id=passwordLabel>Password</LABEL> <INPUT class=txtBox onkeydown="javascript: return checkIt(event, this);" style="MARGIN-LEFT: 1px" size=30 type=password value="" name=PASSWORD AUTOCOMPLETE="off">

Comment: Continue: <INPUT type=hidden value=/initiation/ name=target> <INPUT type=hidden name=smquerydata> <INPUT type=hidden value=0 name=smauthreason> <INPUT type=hidden name=postpreservationdata><INPUT type=hidden value=iOr3TY6kZVQz7iVu+OvCb9/qzklUcsZCN75/b6SVqTW0N1HWdkqcPd6LgvlJVDrk name=smagentname>  <INPUT onclick=submitForm(); class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type=button value="Sign On"> </FORM>

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-mini.btn-primary[value='Sign On'][onclick^='submitForm']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-mini btn-primary' and @value='Sign On'][starts-with(@onclick, 'submitForm')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: let me take a look with this code and i let you know the result

Comment: With cssSelector, i got the follow error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: input.btn btn-mini btn-primary[value='Sign On'][onclick^='submitForm'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval) at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:113)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:283)
at automation_TI_CR.test_ti.main(test_ti.java:32)

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.cssSelector: input.btn btn-mini btn-primary[value='Sign On'][onclick^='submitForm']

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, reading a lots of issues related with this. I'm working with win 10 and IE 11, so, Selenium has a problem with this, because need the size of the text, apps, and others items in 100%. In my case, i had this configuration in 150%. Fixing this, i run the script one again and it works.

The code used is:

```
WebElement button = null;
List<WebElement> inputs = webDriver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
for (WebElement input : inputs) {
    if (input.getAttribute("value").equals("Log In")) {
        button = input;
        break;
    }
}
if (button == null) {
    System.err.println("Cannot find button!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Clicking button now!");
    button.click();
}
```

After this, i check another code more efficient:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][value='Sign On']")).click();
```

This works too.

thanks all off you for your help